# How to split elements into different lines according to their group?

Tags: python, unix, output

How to split all elements into different lines according to their group using Unix command or Python/perl?

## input file:

```
Group1        m1 m2 m3 
Group2        m4 
Group3        m5 m6
```

## Output:

```
m1 Group1
m2 Group1
m3 Group1
m4 Group2
m5 Group3
m6 Group3
```

Comment: SO isn't a code writing service. What have you tried? Please post your code. What worked or didn't work?

Comment: Of course I tried something. I posted because I do not know what to do and I want to learn. I have a perl script that works, but I need to have each line in one separate file and run for each file. But my file has 800 lines, so of course is not a good idea and it is not a good code for it. I need something different, but I do not know how to do it in a simple way. Sorry if  am not an advanced programmer, I though this group was to learn as well.

Comment: Are those tabs between the Groups and the values (ie between Group1 and m1...)?

Comment: yes, there are tabs between all elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep it simple:

```
awk '{for(i=2;i<=NF;++i)print $i, $1}' input_file
```

Comment: very simple and effective. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You could read the file and output it like this:

```
with open("read.txt", "r") as infile:
    groups = {}
    for i in infile:
        groups[i.split("        ")[0].split("Group")[1]] = i.strip("\n").split("        ")[1].split(" ")

with open("output.txt", "w") as outfile:
    for i in range(len(groups)):
        for j in groups[str(i+1)]:
            if j != "":
                outfile.write("Group"+str(i+1)+" "+j+"\n")
```

The dictionary groups contains all m* elements for a group. When the output file is written, we can iterate over the groups and m* in those groups and write them to the output file line by line.

Answer (score 2):

Assume your input file name is "input.txt".

```
all_members = dict()
with open('input.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        line_tokens = line.split()
        group_members = line_tokens[1:]
        for member in group_members:
            all_members[member] = line_tokens[0]

for member in sorted(all_members.keys()):
    print '{} {}'.format(member, all_members[member])
```

This prints out:

```
m1 Group1
m2 Group1
m3 Group1
m4 Group2
m5 Group3
m6 Group3
```

Answer (score 1):

You can split the string, and then use a dictionary to store them:

```
# go through each line in the file, and split into a dict
members = {}
for group, member_string in (x.split('\t', 1) for x in groups_file):
    members.update({member: group for member in member_string.split()})

# print the resulting elements from the dict
for member in sorted(members):
    print(member, members[member])
```

Using this data:

```
groups_file = [x.strip() for x in """
    Group1\tm1 m2 m3
    Group2\tm4
    Group3\tm5 m6
""".split('\n')[1:-1]]
```

Prints this data:

```
m1 Group1
m2 Group1
m3 Group1
m4 Group2
m5 Group3
m6 Group3
```